# Filtering notifications by recipient

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem to create a notifications hub where each user can see when someone added a question to one of their comments (questions belong to comments). To do this i'm tracking the question model like so:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
  tracked recipient: ->(controller, model) { model && model.comment.user }
end
```

In my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include PublicActivity::StoreController     
end
```

The problem is I obviously only want the recipient seeing the notification and cannot seem to get this to work.

Here is the notifications controller that gives me next error:

```
undefined local variable or method `recipient'
```

controller action:

```
def notifications 
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient.id == current_user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should change `notifications` action to :

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
               .where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: Was just about to reply that your comment doesn't quite work but this method does, so thanks!